# grunt-init template conditional copy files

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-init

I've just started using grunt-init. I have everything working. 
And I was wondering if there is a way to do conditional copy root files based on  prompts which based on answers to previous prompts.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `rename.json` file via the [docs](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding#renaming-or-excluding-template-files).

The prop should be the path to the file you want to copy/not copy, and the value can be a template string with a conditional. For example, let's say you had two different `main.js` files, one empty and one with code you tend to re-use:

```
{
  "app/js/main-empty.js": "{% if (empty) { %}app/js/main.js{% } %}",
  "app/js/main-skeleton.js": "{% if (!empty) { %}app/js/main.js{% } %}"
}
```

The `destpath` checks the value of the `props.empty` variable from your `template.js` file, copies and renames correctly.

Here is a [link to a gist](https://gist.github.com/JoshuaJones/b189b3d180450a633983) showing the `template.js` and `rename.js` for that example.