# grunt-init template exclude files from init.filesToCopy(props)

Tags: templates, gruntjs, copy, rename, grunt-init

I've just started using grunt-init. I have everything working. And I was wondering if there is a way to exclude files from copying based on answers to prompts.

```
'use strict';

exports.description = 'Create module';

exports.warnOn = '*';

exports.template = function(grunt, init, done){

    init.process([
        init.prompt('name'),
        {
            name: 'service',
            message: 'Do you need service?',
            default: 'Y/n',
            warning: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'collection',
            message: 'Do you need collection?',
            default: 'Y/n',
            warning: ''
        }
    ], function(err, props){

        var files = init.filesToCopy(props);

        init.copyAndProcess(files, props);

        done();
    });
};
```

rename.js file

```
{
  "bootstrap-module/src/bootstrap-module/bootstrap.collection.js"     : "{%= name %}-module/src/{%= name %}-module/{%= name %}.collection.js",
  "bootstrap-module/src/bootstrap-module/bootstrap.controller.js"     : "{%= name %}-module/src/{%= name %}-module/{%= name %}.controller.js",
  "bootstrap-module/src/bootstrap-module/bootstrap.model.js"          : "{%= name %}-module/src/{%= name %}-module/{%= name %}.model.js",
  "bootstrap-module/src/bootstrap-module/bootstrap.service.js"        : "{%= name %}-module/src/{%= name %}-module/{%= name %}.service.js",
  "bootstrap-module/src/bootstrap-module/bootstrap.view.js"           : "{%= name %}-module/src/{%= name %}-module/{%= name %}.view.js",
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784736/grunt-init-template-conditional-copy-files) implementation didn't help also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@francesca I think your filename should be `rename.json` instead of `rename.js`.

> The template directory structure needs to be like this: 
>   `-> SampleTemplate
>      -> root
>      - rename.json
>      - template.js`

Ref:

[Read this William Walker's - great blog post from here](http://williamwalker.me/blog/levelling-up-with-grunt-project-scaffolding-with-grunt-init.html)

OR

[Read the official documentation for more](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding#custom-templates)

Cheers!